# Authentication and loading localstorage slow on nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm having a problem with nextJS. When I'm logged in, when I go back to the site or load another page, it starts reloading localstorage.

[here is the error video i am getting](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tUgSXzLSbN7nD5JFNC7gQywxajv7t_FF?usp=sharing)

Why is it that when I reload the page, it's not the dark theme but the light theme and then the color changes? And why does it show the login button and then the image and user name?

my code

theme mode

```
'use client';
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

type ThemeContextValue = {
  toggle: () => void;
  mode: string;
};

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextValue>(
  {} as ThemeContextValue,
);

type ThemeProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ThemeProvider: React.FC<ThemeProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<string>('light');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedMode = window.localStorage.getItem('themeMode');
    if (storedMode) {
      setMode(storedMode);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('themeMode', mode);
  }, [mode]);

  const toggle = () => {
    setMode((prev) => (prev === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ toggle, mode }}>
      <div className={`theme ${mode}`}>{children}</div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

my code login

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import connect from '../../../../../server/connect-mongodb';
import User from '../../../../../models/Users';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    // @ts-ignore
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'Credentials',
      async authorize(credentials) {
        //Check if the user exists.
        await connect();

        try {
          const user = await User.findOne({
            // @ts-ignore
            email: credentials.email,
          });

          if (user) {
            const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
              // @ts-ignore
              credentials.password,
              user.password,
            );

            if (isPasswordCorrect) {
              return user;
            } else {
              throw new Error('Wrong Credentials!');
            }
          } else {
            throw new Error('User not found!');
          }
        } catch (err: any) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }
      },
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      // @ts-ignore
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      // @ts-ignore
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    error: '/auth/sign-in',
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

```
const params: any = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  // if have account change to home
  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      router.push('/');
    }
  }, [session, router]);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setError(params.get('error'));
    setSuccess(params.get('success'));
  }, [params]);

  // function login with Google
  const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await signIn('google');
      if (result?.error) {
        console.error('Google sign-in error:', result.error);
      } else if (result?.ok) {
        router.push('/');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Google sign-in error:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = e.target[0].value;
    const password = e.target[1].value;

    setLoading(true);

    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      email,
      password,
      redirect: false, // Prevent automatic redirect
    });
    setLoading(false);
    if (result?.error) {
      setErrorMessage('Tên tài khoản hoặc mật khẩu không chính xác');
    } else if (result?.ok) {
      router.push('/');
    }
  };
```

can you tell me why i got that error?